# pass variables to child process using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, multithreading, process, processbuilder

I'd like to know whether it is possible to pass variables to a process in Java.

For example, if I create a new process with the process builder, and I want the new child process to add two variables from the parent process, how would I go about it?

Comment: What do you mean by variables? Environment variables? Command line parameters?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. ProcessBuilder creates separate processes (not Java threads). Hence you cannot access a java variable from the newly created process. If you want to have shared memory between parent and child, then you need to use threads.

Comment: You are right, you cannot share variables without some extra effort. My question is, how would you then like to do it? There are many ways of doing that. If simply passing some values from parent to child would suffice, you could simply pass these as cmd. line parameters, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I'll have to take a different approach then.. cheers